# can't change the background image for a button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I created a button image in photoshop but when i use it on the app it just crash i guess i need a specify dimension the app work fine without background image for the button

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: button background]

Comment: What's your crash log?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `ImageButton` instead of `Button`?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="sourceDrawableHere"/>
```

Comment: image button don t take text

Comment: if text is required and you have tried     android:background="@drawable/button_bg" on a normal button then can i see your crash log?

Comment: i couldn t add the crash log they say ''It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.''

Comment: Can you grab an image of it and post into your original question? Might be able to see something there

Comment: the most interesting part in the crash log is Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f030002 a=-1 r=0x7f030002}

Comment: so i just paste the image on both drawable and drawable v24 and it works i had problems with the gradle earlier and i had to paste org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
org.gradle.daemon=true  for it to work then i had errors that i never seen working with android studio is pain in the *** pff :'(